# Nonetype object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/tucson).read())
for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'rpad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
  tds = row('td')
  print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

Receives error "Nonetype object not callable" while executing

Comment: You forgot to close the URL string. You need a `'` after `tucson`, so its `'http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/tucson'`

Comment: Provide the exceptions stacktrace please...

Comment: You are calling a method on None. Find out what in your code is None and you will be led to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/tucson').read())

>>> print soup('table', {'class' : 'rpad'})[0]
<table class="rpad"><tr><td>Location:</td><td>Davis-Monthan Air Force Base</td></tr><tr><td>Temperature:</td><td>25&nbsp;°C</td></tr><tr><td>Comfort Level:</td><td>26&nbsp;°C</td></tr><tr><td>Dew point:</td><td>21&nbsp;°C</td></tr><tr><td>Pressure:</td><td>1009 millibars</td></tr><tr><td>Humidity:</td><td>77%</td></tr><tr><td>Visibility:</td><td>16 km</td></tr><tr><td>Wind:</td><td>11 km/h from 280&deg; West<img src="http://c.tadst.com/gfx/comp/sa8.png" width="14" height="14" alt="Direction East" title="Wind blowing from West to East" /></td></tr><tr><td>Last update:</td><td>Tue 9:55 PM MST</td></tr></table>

>>> 'tbody' in soup('table', {'class' : 'rpad'})[0]
False
>>> print soup('table', {'class' : 'rpad'})[0].tbody
None
```

`None` is not callable, i.e. you can't call `None('tr')`

Answer (score 3):

If you see the page source of your url

> http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/usa/tucson

, the `table` element with class `rpad` does not have
a `tbody` child element.

`<table class=rpad><tr><td>Location:</td><td>Davis-Monthan Air Force Base</td></tr><tr><td>Temperature:....`

You need to extract data keeping this structure in mind. Directly traverse the `tr` and `td` elements.